# Check two conditions in line

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following lines and I want to match the first one based one the condition that it starts with a '%' and contains a '=' sign:

```
% This comment is = True

% This comment is equal true
```

I want to use python's `re` module to be able to extract the first sentence on the basis that it starts with a `%` and contains a `=`.

So far, I have gathered that I need something like:

```
...
if re.match('^%' ,line):
    ...
```

but cannot figure out the rest. Thank you!

Comment: Try  something like `^%.*=`

Comment: This is trivial, you need to read a regexp tutorial.

Comment: try r'^%.*=.*' ?

Comment: Should `%=` be valid or invalid?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Why the lookahead instead of just matching it normally?

Comment: For developing and testing regexes, try online sites like regex101; they let you experiment, show how the regex matches and explain what it means

Comment: Do not use regex here: `if text.startswith('%') and '=' in text:`

Comment: I agree regex is trivial here, and not needed. But still, the question needs to be asked. Thanks so much, @sabik got it, checking below answers soon too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. regex is marginally useful if you don't want to allow `%=`. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need regex for this:

```
if line[0] == '%' and '=' in line:
```

OR

```
if line.startswith('%') and '=' in line:
```

That being said, you can use regex like this:

```
if re.match('%.*='):
```

Or better yet:

```
pattern = re.compile('%.*=')

...

if pattern.match(line):
```

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) already implies that your regex begins with `^`.

If you don't want to allow `%=`, you still don't really need regex, but it's a bit simpler to use it. Without regex you can do something like

```
if line[0] == '%' and line[1] != '=' and '=' in line[2:]:
```

Using regex, you can do

```
if re.match('%[^=]+=', line):
```

I would argue that the second is more elegant.

Comment: I'll accept this. Thanks. I agree, regex is not needed, but I had to still know it for here. So, are you saying that the '^' character is redundant with re.match, and that it already is accounted for?

Comment: @Mad Physicist - Thank you very much for the great answer!

Comment: @dawg. I did. See the middle (used to be the end) of the post. Specifically "re.match already implies that your regex begins with ^."

Comment: @user1029384756. I linked to the docs so you could verify that.

Comment: There is a difference between `'%.*='` and `'%[^=]+='` worth noting. The second will match `\n` and the first will not.

Comment: @dawg. OP is specifically talking about comparing single lines, so I would argue against adding unnecessary detail to the answer in this case. That being said, your comment is valuable to future readers as such.

Comment: @dawg, can you please explain? - I agree, it is valuabkle

Comment: The difference between [first](https://regex101.com/r/SpgdDH/1/) and [second](https://regex101.com/r/SpgdDH/1/)

Comment: @user1029384756. `.` does not match newlines unless you set the appropriate flag, `[^=]` most certainly does. You should not be affected as long as you are matching individual lines rather than the entire body of text.

Comment: Got it! - Thanks to both of you!